# opus translation for asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I moved my asterisk server from debian to ubuntu because asterisk isnt in bookworm.

I have problems translating to opus. (required for the home assistant voip assistant) and I cant move all to opus due to my granstream voip phones.

With debian i could apt install  asterisk-opus and the translation was added to asterisk.
but this packages has been replaced with a global modules packages. that does not provide translation.

How to resolve this issue.

```
asterisk*CLI> core show translation 
         Translation times between formats (in microseconds) for one second of data
          Source Format (Rows) Destination Format (Columns)

            amr amrwb codec2  ulaw  alaw   gsm  g726 g726aal2 adpcm slin8 slin12 slin16 slin24 slin32 slin44 slin48 slin96 slin192 lpc10 speex8 speex16 speex32  g722 testlaw
      amr     - 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
    amrwb 23500     -  23500 23500 23500 23500 23500    23500 23500 17500  17500   9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 23500  23500   15000   23000 15000   23500
   codec2 15000 23000      - 15000 15000 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
     ulaw 15000 23000  15000     -  9150 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
     alaw 15000 23000  15000  9150     - 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
      gsm 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000     - 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
     g726 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000     -    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
 g726aal2 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000 15000        - 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
    adpcm 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000 15000    15000     -  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
    slin8  6000 14000   6000  6000  6000  6000  6000     6000  6000     -   8000   8000   8000   8000   8000   8000   8000    8000  6000   6000   14000   14000  8250    6000
   slin12 14500 14000  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500      -   8000   8000   8000   8000   8000   8000    8000 14500  14500   14000   14000 14000   14500
   slin16 14500  6000  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500      -   8000   8000   8000   8000   8000    8000 14500  14500    6000   14000  6000   14500
   slin24 14500 14500  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500   8500      -   8000   8000   8000   8000    8000 14500  14500   14500   14000 14500   14500
   slin32 14500 14500  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500   8500   8500      -   8000   8000   8000    8000 14500  14500   14500    6000 14500   14500
   slin44 14500 14500  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500   8500   8500   8500      -   8000   8000    8000 14500  14500   14500   14500 14500   14500
   slin48 14500 14500  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500   8500   8500   8500   8500      -   8000    8000 14500  14500   14500   14500 14500   14500
   slin96 14500 14500  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500   8500   8500   8500   8500   8500      -    8000 14500  14500   14500   14500 14500   14500
  slin192 14500 14500  14500 14500 14500 14500 14500    14500 14500  8500   8500   8500   8500   8500   8500   8500   8500       - 14500  14500   14500   14500 14500   14500
    lpc10 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000     -  15000   23000   23000 17250   15000
   speex8 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000      -   23000   23000 17250   15000
  speex16 23500 15000  23500 23500 23500 23500 23500    23500 23500 17500  17500   9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 23500  23500       -   23000 15000   23500
  speex32 23500 23500  23500 23500 23500 23500 23500    23500 23500 17500  17500  17500  17500   9000  17000  17000  17000   17000 23500  23500   23500       - 23500   23500
     g722 15600 15000  15600 15600 15600 15600 15600    15600 15600  9600  17500   9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15600  15600   15000   23000     -   15600
  testlaw 15000 23000  15000 15000 15000 15000 15000    15000 15000  9000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000  17000   17000 15000  15000   23000   23000 17250       -
```

Answer (score 0):

apt-file search codec_opus.so does not show anything.
fixed following: http://asterisktutorials.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-install-and-use-opus-codec-in.html

1. Go to link, http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/codec_opus/

   Here select appropriate Asterisk version of your installation and then server architecture. In my case it was Asterisk 13 with 64-bit.
2. Now download file:

   ```
   cd /usr/src  
   wget http://downloads.digium.com/pub/telephony/codec_opus/asterisk-13.0/x86-64/codec_opus-13.0_current-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract the downloaded file.

   ```
   tar -xvzf codec_opus-13.0_current-x86_64.tar.gz
   cd codec_opus-13.0_1.1.0-x86_64
   ```
4. Copy the codec_opus.so file into the Asterisk module directory

   ```
   cp codec_opus.so /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/
   ```
5. Copy the codec_opus_config-en_US.xml file into the Asterisk external documentation directory

   ```
   cp codec_opus_config-en_US.xml /var/lib/asterisk/documentation/thirdparty
   ```
6. Go to Asterisk CLI and restart it.

   ```
   asterisk -rvvvv
   core restart now
   asterisk -rvvvv
   core reload
   ```
7. Now check if opus codec is running or not with the below command.

   ```
   ubuntu*CLI> module show like opus
   Module Description Use Count Status Support Level
   codec_opus.so OPUS Coder/Decoder 0 Running extended
   res_format_attr_opus.so Opus Format Attribute Module 1 Running core
   ```

   If module not loaded, then try to load it manually from the Asterisk CLI.

   ```
   module load codec_opus.so
   module load res_format_attr_opus.so
   ```
8. Open file, nano `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf` and allow opus codec in it as shown below, so SIP soft phones can use that codec.

   ```
   [general]
   callcounter=yes ; enable device states for SIP devices
   rtcachefriends=yes
   udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0:5060
   disallow=all
   allow=opus
   allow=ulaw
   allow=alaw
   allow=gsm
   ```

   After adding, run `sip reload` from Asterisk CLI to enable changes.

   ```
   ankit-desktop*CLI> sip reload
   Reloading SIP
   == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/sip.conf': Found
   == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/users.conf': Found
   == Using SIP CoS mark 4
   == Parsing '/etc/asterisk/sip_notify.conf': Found
   ankit-desktop*CLI>
   ```